# Verb in sentence with "take care that"

Tags: grammar

In [Article Two of the United States Constitution](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj33-fq08POAhWHfxoKHUZYCEgQFggeMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FArticle_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution&usg=AFQjCNGoNP9wQGL9piHqFVRZDS-Af32e1Q&sig2=IaCJxsvPv0Y4EfI0689agA&bvm=bv.129422649,d.d2s&cad=rja) there is this Statement:

> shall take Care that the Laws **be** faithfully executed

Now I want to know whether **"be"** can or should be replaced by **"are"**, and why is it not in the said Statement.

Comment: "are" would be more usual, nowadays.  It's an old document and that usage of "be" is quite archaic now.

Comment: @Max Williams There have been other discussions here about the option of using the indicative rather than an irrealis mood. I'd certainly use 'are' here, but I'm not sure that 'quite archaic' fits, and I'm fairly sure you can expect some flak.

Comment: Related:[Why is American English so wedded to the subjunctive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76578/why-is-american-english-so-wedded-to-the-subjunctive).

Comment: Irrealis is instanced solely by "were". Your first example is subjunctive; replacing "be" with "are" gives a declarative clause.

Comment: @Edwin: Is AmE really that "wedded to the subjunctive"? Surely if they were writing that clause today it would be ***...will [must?] ensure** that the laws **are** faithfully executed.*

Comment: @FF Hey, I want to visit the States again sometime. If people over there want to pronounce 'Arkansas' (the river) two different ways, that's their prerogative. There are three ways of pronouncing 'Shrewsbury'. I think the Americans are only as idiosyncratic as we Brits are.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : No, I wouldn't use that form, and I know many others wouldn't.

Comment: @Michael: Are you seriously saying you would *prefer* to use the subjunctive? Wow! You really are happily married! (To a corpse, imho, but I guess beauty is in the eye of the beholder! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Certainly.  Why not?  Some uses of the subjunctive have died out, but not that one.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Taking note of the shambles Americans have made re interpretations of *the right to bear arms,* I think it's a bad idea to assume precise choice of words unambiguously and permanently fixes "meaning". The bottom line is both context *and* actual usage make far more difference. I don't deny there's *some* substance to the distinction you make. But I think that *It is important that you be here,* for example, could be exactly equivalent to *...that you **are** here.* And no such distinction can be made anyway with *...that you love me*, so it's not even universally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

> It is important that John is at the meeting.
>
> It is important that John be at the meeting.

To me these two sentences have different meanings.  The first presuppose it to be a fact that John is at the meeting, and says that fact is important.  The second requires or recommends or prescribes John's attendance at the meeting.

I think many in England, and some in America, do not use the second form in the present day.